# Selecting the text out of an <a> element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, select, text

I'm trying to grab the text section of this html:

```
<li class="location"><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
```

with this jQuery:

```
$('.location').off('click').click(function() {
alert($(this).children('a')[0].text());
}
```

So that my alert displays "Some Text". I'm just not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method is provided by jQuery wrapper element, `children('a')[0]` gives an DOM element which does not have that method.

Using the getter format of `text()` returns the text content of the first element in the given set which is what you are looking for

```
$('.location').off('click').click(function () {
    alert($(this).children('a').text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up having a small error in another part of my code but your answer was very helpful to this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.location').off('click').click(function () {
alert($(this).children('a').html());
```

});